# Ref-qualified member functions design breaks on const rvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I have a `Maybe` class that is a stack-based class that might contain the given type.  We have certain functions that return a `Maybe` containing a mutable or const reference.  This is mostly to reduce boilerplate, look-ups, and unneeded copies.

```
Map<String, Foo> map;

// Normal C++
auto it = map.find("foo");
if (it != map.end())
  doStuff(*it);

// Has an extra lookup, bad
if (map.contains("foo"))
  doStuff(map.get("foo"));

// Uses Maybe
if (auto val = map.maybe("foo"))
  doStuff(*val);

// Also possible:
// apply calls the function with *this as argument if this is valid
map.maybe("foo").apply(&doStuff);
```

However, this is problematic when `map` is a temporary:

```
Map<String, Foo> map;
Map<String, Foo> getMap() { return map; } // Returns a copy of map

if (auto val = getMap().maybe("foo")) // Returns Maybe<Foo&> to temporary
  doStuff(*val); // Very bad, *val has already been deleted
```

On the other hand, because the `Maybe<Foo>` is constructible from `Maybe<Foo&>` (in general, `Maybe<T2>` is constructible from `Maybe<T>` if `T2` is constructible from `T`) then if I write this, it is not a problem.

```
if (Maybe<Foo> val = getMap().maybe("foo"))
  doStuff(*val); // OK, val contains a copy
```

After a coworker stumbled into this problem, I had the bright idea to use ref-qualified member functions in places that might return a `Maybe<T&>` to return a `Maybe<T>` instead, if it's an rvalue.

```
Maybe<Val> Map<Key, Val>::maybe(Key const& key) &&;
Maybe<Val const&> Map<Key, Val>::maybe(Key const& key) const&;
Maybe<Val &> Map<Key, Val>::maybe(Key const& key) &;
```

But I'm having some trouble figuring out what to do in the case of `const&&;`

If left without, it would call the `const&` version, which is bad, because that would return a reference.

I considered making the `&&` version a `const&&` version to avoid repetition; however, then I would need to copy, instead of moving the internal value.  And I don't understand enough about the semantics of `const&&` to know if it would be acceptable to `const_cast` internally, or if that would cause madness and hysteria while I mutate the `const&&`.  I'd rather not have to write two copies of this function, if I don't have to.

What is normal best practice in this situation?  Do I need to write all 4 functions?  Or can I get away sanely with 3?

Is there a better way to avoid this dangling reference problem?  This is only a problem because `auto` normally strips away references, so you can't accidentally take a reference to a temporary, but because the type of a `Maybe` is already a plain value, it's just wrapping a reference type, it becomes possible to shoot yourself in the foot.  Just saying "well don't use `auto` in that case then," is very tempting, but it's still really easy to accidentally mess up, and I'd rather it be difficult to do the wrong thing.

Comment: This question probably has too much context, but I was trying to avoid an XY problem scenario.

Comment: Any reason you don't just `delete` the `const&&`-variant? I mean, it seems pathological. Also, I'm not really sure how to get a `const&&` without deliberately casting to it, or implicit conversion from one of the other varieties...

Comment: It didn't really cross my mind to `delete` it, but I'm also not certain that this would be acceptable behavior, or if it would be surprising.

Comment: @Deduplicator Given something like `const Map<Key, Val> f();`, `f().maybe("key")` would call the `const&&`-qualified `maybe`. `const&&` doesn't turn up in typical programs because most of us realize that returning `const T` from a function is a bad idea, even if the language does allow it when `T` is a class type.

Comment: @Casey: Thanks, so even if I lost track of all the ways to get it, it is still pathological. And just `delete`-ing it still looks like the right way to make sure, even if with sane APIs there's no danger of calling it accidentally anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes - I would absolutely delete it, unless I just *had* to interoperate with someone else's poorly designed code. In that case I'd implement it to return by value as in the `&&` case but to copy instead of move from the `Map`: `Maybe<V> maybe(Key const& key) const&& { return maybe(key); }` delegates implementation to the `const&` overload and is reasonably terse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you would get a `const&&` in good code anyway.

The only ways are

1. Calling a function returning a `const T`. (And having such a return-type is a bad idea anyway.)
2. Calling a function returning a `const T&&`. (Dito.)
3. Deliberately casting to `const&&`. (Which you won't do anyway.)
4. Implicit conversion from `&&`. (Which won't happen, because you have an overload accepting by r-value reference.)

Thus, the proper way if you want to bullet-proof your API is just `delete`-ing that overload:

```
Maybe<Val &> maybe(Key const& key) const&& = delete;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that this isn't really a problem. Consider the program

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  int& x = std::map<int, int>{{3, 4}}[3];
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Reference `x` will be dangling after the map is destroyed (making the last line undefined behaviour). The standard library does nothing to prevent this kind of situation.

I've also never heard of anyone accidentally making this kind of mistake.

With your map, it's the same situation.

IMO, returning either `Maybe<Val>` or `Maybe<Val&>` depending on the value category of the map is too confusing. Just think twice every time you call `.maybe` on a temporary object.